# Can I install gnome 3.12 on ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, gnome

Like my questions says. Can I install gnome 3.12 on ubuntu 12.04?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot install. It can be installed only on Ubuntu 14.04+.

Currently even on 14.04, its not recommended. It breaks Unity. Hence I recommend installing Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 to use gnome 3.12